# Rcpp: Eliminating a column and a row from a matrix

Tags: rcpp

I am trying to create a function that takes a matrix, *n x p*, and an index, *e*, and returns the sub-matrix obtained by eliminating the *e-th* column and the *e-th* row from X. I thought that the easiest thing was to create an *n -1 x p - 1* matrix and insert the corners around the *cross* formed by the *e-th* row and column in it. The same approach works fine with EigenRcpp using the *Corner* syntax. It seems that `Rcpp` doesn't like assignment to Ranges. I get the following Error message:

`error: non-static reference member 'Rcpp::SubMatrix<14>::MATRIX& Rcpp::SubMatrix<14>::m', can't use default assignment operator`

I copy the code below.

My questions:
How do I assign values to a block of a matrix?
Is there a better way to do this?

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

NumericMatrix elimMat(NumericMatrix X, int e){

int p = X.cols() - 1;
int n = X.rows() - 1;
int f = e - 1;
NumericMatrix M = NumericMatrix(n, p);

M(Range(0, f - 1), Range(0, f - 1)) = X(Range(0, f - 1), Range(0, f - 1)); //TopLeft same
M(Range(0, f - 1), Range(f, p - 1)) = X(Range(0, f - 1), Range(f + 1, p)); //TopRight
M(Range(f, n - 1), Range(0, f - 1)) = X(Range(f + 1, n), Range(0, f - 1)); //BottomLeft
M(Range(f, n - 1), Range(f, p - 1)) = X(Range(f + 1, n), Range(f + 1, p)); //BottomRight

return M;
}
```

Thanks for any help, Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding this error,

> error: non-static reference member  ‘Rcpp::SubMatrix<14>::MATRIX&
>   Rcpp::SubMatrix<14>::m’,  can’t use default assignment operator

I don't think there is anything you (or anyone on the client side) can do about this since the problem is coming from the [class definition](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/SubMatrix.h) of `SubMatrix`. According to the compiler,

```cpp
private:
    MATRIX& m ;
    vec_iterator iter ;
    int m_nr, nc, nr ;
```

`m` should be a `static` member, and it's not, hence the error.

---

Although I can't give you a general work-around for using `Range` assignments in this manner, here is one possible approach to your specific question about "crossing out" a section of a `NumericMatrix`:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix crossout(Rcpp::NumericMatrix X, int e) {
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix result = Rcpp::no_init_matrix(X.nrow() - 1, X.ncol() - 1);
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix::iterator src = X.begin(), dst = result.begin();

  while (src != X.end()) {
    if (((src - X.begin()) % X.nrow()) != e && ((src - X.begin()) / X.nrow()) != e) {
      *dst = *src;
      ++dst;
    }
    ++src;
  }

  return result;
}
```

---

```r
/*** R

M <- matrix(1:9 + .5, nrow = 3)
R> all.equal(M[c(1, 3), c(1, 3)], crossout(M, 1))
#[1] TRUE

R> crossout(M, 1)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  1.5  7.5
#[2,]  3.5  9.5

M2 <- matrix(1:20 + .5, nrow = 4)
R> all.equal(M2[c(1:2, 4), c(1:2, 4:5)], crossout(M2, 2))
#[1] TRUE

R> crossout(M2, 2)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  1.5  5.5 13.5 17.5
#[2,]  2.5  6.5 14.5 18.5
#[3,]  4.5  8.5 16.5 20.5

R> any(unique(c(M2[3,], M2[,3])) %in% crossout(M2, 2))
#[1] FALSE

*/
```

---

Above, I'm copying the current value of the "source" iterator to the "destination" iterator if the source iterator's position does not fall within the column or row specified by `e`. The row index is obtained as `(src - X.begin()) % X.nrow()`, and the column index is obtained as `(src - X.begin()) / X.nrow()`.

---

**Edit:** 
Regarding your comment below, it would be pretty straightforward to accomodate non-square matrices / differing indices for the row and column dimensions:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix crossout2(Rcpp::NumericMatrix X, int r, int c) {
  if (r >= X.nrow() || c >= X.ncol()) {
    Rf_error("Invalid row or column index.\n");
  }

  Rcpp::NumericMatrix result = Rcpp::no_init_matrix(X.nrow() - 1, X.ncol() - 1);
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix::iterator src = X.begin(), dst = result.begin();

  while (src != X.end()) {
    if (((src - X.begin()) % X.nrow()) != r && ((src - X.begin()) / X.nrow()) != c) {
      *dst = *src;
      ++dst;
    }
    ++src;
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

Comment: Fantastic, your code is complicated for my level!  Thanks!

It runs slightly faster than  `R> X[-e, -e]`, which is slightly faster than my RcppEigen code. It crashes if *e* is larger than the number of rows or columns. But it's ok for me as I plan to use it on square matrices.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to criticise. It was more of a warning for someone else using the code. Thanks a lot for your great help!